# 0-1 non convex quadratic problem in CPLEX

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, binary-programming

Can CPLEX solve non-convex 0-1 quadratic optimization problem? If so, does anyone know how?

Comment: With appropriate serttng of solutiontarget, CPLEX can solve non-convex 0-1 quadratic optimization problems, provided that the non-convexities are in the objective function, and not in the constraints.

Comment: This question should NOT be closed. I answered the question in my above comment.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please let me know how could I set appropriate solution target?

Comment: Whoops, I meant optimalitytarget, which is the new name for it.  See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/OptimalityTarget.html .If CLPEX is invoked from certain non-IBM higher level optimization modeling tools, the tool might have a higher level or different interface to set this, or might even do it "under the hood", without requiring your active setting of it.

Comment: BTW, starting with Gurobi 9.0, it can handle non-convex quadratics in the objective function and/or the constraints.

Comment: Thanks again. I am new with CPLEX. Not sure what do you mean by non-IBM higher level optimization modeling tools? I downloaded CPLEX from the IBM website and could not figure out changing the optimality target yet.

Comment: Optimization Modeling tools such as AMPL GAMS, and YALMIP, Pyomo, among many others. These tools allow you to enter the problem once, then easily switch between different solvers without reentering the problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark L. Stone. CPLEX is unable to solve the problem as it is a large scale problem. With more than 10 running hours, the gap is more than 10%. One of the constraints is non-convex and been relaxed by introducing a new variable with the appropriate constraints. Any trick can be used so that CPLEX get an optimal solution. Does CPLEX do Lagrangian relaxation? If not, where can I find its code as I am not good in coding

Comment: The code is proprietary to IBM. Large scale problems might solve fast, or take the life of the universe. 10% gap in 10 hours isn't that bad. You have to decide what gap you're to accept. There are many parameters which can be adjusted. if you post your model and solver log, you might get some suggestions on the IBM Decision Optimization forum  https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home?communitykey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7 which may bet answers by CPLEX specialists at IBM. You may have to wait a few days until you get a reply.

Comment: Does relaxing the variable to be continuous and $\in \[0,1\]$ make the problem non convex? I tried that with CPLEX and I am getting this message? Then I changed the "type of solution to compute" from automatic to Global optimal solution. From my little knowledge, relaxing the variables give a lower bound and reduce the computational time. But unfortunately I did not get that, and instead CPLEX spent more than 6 hours and did not find any feasible solution. When the variables are binary, in less than 15 minutes CPLEX was able to get the first feasible solution? Please,any explanation???

Comment: I suggest you inquire at https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home?communitykey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7 , which has CPLEX experts fro,m IBM and elsewhere answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a $0$-$1$ quadratic function of $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can always be made convex by adding a sufficiently large multiple of $\sum_i (x_i^2-x_i)$, which is $0$ for binary $x$.

Alternatively, you can linearize a binary quadratic objective by introducing a binary (or just nonnegative) variable $y_{i,j}$ to represent $x_i x_j$, along with linear constraints:
\begin{align}
y_{i,j} &\le x_i \\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j \\
y_{i,j} &\ge x_i + x_j - 1
\end{align}

I don't know whether CPLEX does either of these transformations automatically, but you can do it yourself before calling the solver.

Comment: Introducing a new variable with the linear constraints does not work with my problem as it is a large scale problem. I am not sure what do you mean by adding sufficiently large multiple of $\sum_i (x_i^2-x_i)$? My problem has a multiplication of two variables $x_w$ and $y_s$ that are binary. Does this method work here?

Comment: See Theorem 1 in [Hammer and Rubin (1970)](http://www.numdam.org/article/RO_1970__4_3_67_0.pdf).  The names of the variables don't matter.  If you have $n$ variables, just think of them as being named $x_1,\dots,x_n$.